# Next highest value by time/index

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Is there a way to obtain the next highest value from the first year (*i.e.* 1995), ideally with `dplyr` verbs? For example, the next highest value from 1995 is in 1997, and from 1997 is 1999.

**Example dataset:**

```r
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ year, ~name, ~value,
  1995, "A", 3000,
  1996, "B", 2500,
  1997, "C", 4010,
  1998, "D", 4000,
  1999, "E", 5000,
  2000, "F", 4500
)

dat

#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>    year name  value
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1  1995 A      3000
#> 2  1996 B      2500
#> 3  1997 C      4010
#> 4  1998 D      4000
#> 5  1999 E      5000
#> 6  2000 F      4500
```

I've tried using `arrange()` and `slice_max()` functions but it didn't take into account the year/index.

**Desired output:**

| year | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1995 | A | 3000 |
| 1997 | C | 4010 |
| 1999 | E | 5000 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably we can use `cummax`

```
> subset(dat, cummax(value) == value)
# A tibble: 3 × 3
   year name  value
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1  1995 A      3000
2  1997 C      4010
3  1999 E      5000
```

Comment: Nice option with `cummax`

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for, is called the local maximum/maxima, or local peaks.
Using this term, you can find several packages/functions providing a method to find them, like the one below...

```
library(pracma)
dat[pracma::findpeaks(dat$value, nups = 0)[,2], ]

# A tibble: 3 × 3
   year name  value
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1  1995 A      3000
2  1997 C      4010
3  1999 E      5000
```